# Debug protobuf plugin using vs2022 failed for access is denied

Tags: debugging, plugins, protocol-buffers, visual-studio-2022

When I debugged my protobuf plugin using vs2022, I failed to launch protoc with message

```
Unable to start program 'protoc'.
Access is denied.
```

And my debugging settings:

Command:                      protoc

Command Arguments:            --pbf_out=. -I \path_to_proto

Working Directory:            D:\protoc\bin

Attach:                       no

Debugger Type:                Auto

```
But I could run it through the cmd `protoc --pbf_out -I ...`

BTW. My plugin's name is proto_gen_pbf
So, why the access is denied? How to fix this problem?
```

Answer (score 0):

I find a solution, It works:

Command:

```
<porotoc_path>\protoc&nbsp;**.exe**
```

don't omit the '.exe'

Working Directory: **.**